# Durability issues of sd-cards in phones?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, external-sd

I understand, that there are many factors why a sd-card may fail. But I had my last two sd-cards fail in a very short time (about three months). Now I wonder if it is the phones fault, or if I just by bad sd-cards.

I don't have any brand information about the failing sd-card, because I just looked at the capacity and the price (which might be an indication, that it is my fault). But I did not buy the card from a dubious store, so I was hoping they would have some level of acceptable quality.

Is there a quality measure that I can look out for, when shopping for sd-cards?

**My phone info**: Samsung Galaxy S I9000 with Gingerbread 2.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had bad luck with any "cheap" cards that I ever bought. They usually end up being "off brands", and some of the [slowest performing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Speed_Class_Rating). The cheap ones usually don't even mention the class rating, which means they are probably a class 2, or worse. I never had them fail in the short time you seen, but they did fail, and after 2 cheap cards failed on me in my android device, I spent the extra couple bucks and went with a "name brand" class 6 (I couldn't even find a class 10 when I bought it). I have had this card for almost 3 years now, it has moved between 3 different android devices in that time, and has seen its share of custom android ROMs flashed to the host device. Not to mention it even had a time, before froyo, it was partitioned to with 1GB EXT4 partition to act as an "extension" of the devices internal storage, and even SWAP at one point on my [ADP1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADP1). I have had zero problems with it.